# SequelizeJS Soft Deleting

Tags: sql, database, node.js, sequelize.js

I can't figure out how the soft deleting works with SequelizeJS and I cannot find any documentation online.

I've already setup at a `deletedAt` column as

```
deletedAt: {
    type: Sequelize.DATE
}
```

but I don't know how to now setup the system so that `MyModel.destroy(query)` soft deletes it instead. Currently, it plainly removes the entry completely.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/api/sequelize/#definemodelname-attributes-options-model

Set `options.timestamps` and `options.paranoid` to true - then sequelize will add the `deletedAt` column for you, and set it instead of deleting the row

Comment: can someone explain it,, i'm still searching and not found anything,,
`timestamps: true,paranoid: true`, still only deleted item..

Comment: my fault, my error is i'm wrong to define `deletedAt` as `deleted_at`..
ok, it's solved,,  btw, could we customize it ? source : http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/instances.html

Comment: we can customize it, you create deletedAt column in table, by migrations first, and if you have chosen any different custom name for that column, than you should also specify that custom name in options.deletedAt: 'deleted_at', near the options.paranoid:true .
https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/core-concepts/paranoid/

Answer (score 0):

First Add `deletedAt` column **both** the **model & migrations** file like -

```
deletedAt: {
    type: Sequelize.DATE,
    allowNull: false
}
```

Then set the `timestamps` & `paranoid` to **true**. I think it will be work..